# Connecting Android to MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

So I'm really new to this. I was following a tutorial on web that showed how to connect these two. But everything I do it just jumps to catch part and it says "No connection". What am I missing? I also connect to a http server to use a PHP script which queries username and password from the database.

```
try
    {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
        {
            entity = response.getEntity();

            if(entity != null)
            {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(instream.toString());

                String retUser = jsonResponse.getString("upime");
                String retPass = jsonResponse.getString("geslo");

                if(username.equals(retUser) && password.equals(retPass))
                {
                    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("logindetails", 0);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor spedit = sp.edit();

                    spedit.putString("upime", username);
                    spedit.putString("geslo", password);

                    spedit.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed to login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: can you use give me the output when "No connection" is replaced with e.getMessage()

Comment: If I use e.getMessage() instead of "No connection" string?

Comment: what u r getting ???

Comment: Can this mobile app connect to a JSON API to _retrieve_ a user's username and password? That doesn't sound very safe...

Comment: I got an empty toast message @SamuelJMathew

Comment: I'm just making an application for my school project so safety doesn't really matter for now. I am a beginner in Android studio and I'm still looking for the best ways to do this. @halfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 
 header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
 $dbhost ="localhost"; 
 $dbuser = "username"; 
 $dbpass = "password"; 
 $dbdb = "db"; 
 $connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("connection error"); 

 mysql_select_db($dbdb);
 $username =$_POST['username'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$username' AND pass='$password'");

  $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($num == 1) 
{ 
 while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
 { $output = $list; 
 }
  mysql_close(); 


 echo json_encode($output);


?>
```

edit the final **"echou"** to **echo** and add

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Now if that's correct, I guess i have a ton of "bugs" in the Java code then.

Comment: You should debug and seewhere it fails

Answer (score 0):

You have to create webservice in which php code is written. web service can be soap and Rest. and you have to write url of webservice in http client object.

By doing this you can connect android and mysql.

```
HttpPost postD=new HttpPost("url");
```

Comment: I do have this written right before the try clause.
'httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost("script.php");'

Answer (score 0):

Have you given Internet Permission in your android manifest?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes I have given the permission.

Comment: post your php code here.Do you set json as the header of the returned values in the PHP? header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: ' <?php

$dbhost ="localhost";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbdb = "db";

$connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("connection error");
mysql_select_db($dbdb);

$username =$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$username' AND pass='$password'");

$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num == 1)
{
 while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
 {
  $output = $list;

  echou json_encode($output);
 }
 mysql_close();
}

?> '

Where should i set json as the header?